# Outdated Trusted Root Certification Authority in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, ssl-certificate, trusted-root-certificates

I can't access any of the Google websites (primarily) because of an "untrusted security certificate".

From what I've found, it seems that the Trusted Root Certification Authorities Store is outdated.

I found an [article on TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/google-in-the-enterprise/the-strange-case-of-the-google-certificate-roadblock/1292) that describes my exact problem in detail, but the only problem is that the fix he used for it *doesn't work*.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: I've checked _everything_. I know what the problem is, and it's described in that article. I just have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Windows 7 Pro x64. 
I'm sorry if I'm confusing, but I have no idea how to better explain it. The issue that the author of the article was having is _exactly_ what's happening to me. I tried downloading the update that fixed it for him, and it did absolutely nothing for me.

Comment: There is a *big* difference between the issue in the article and yours.  The article targets small companies who are having problems because their websites are often not signed by one of the big universally-trusted Root CAs.  The problem *you* are having is with accessing the website of one *really big* company who *does* have SSL certs signed by one of the regular Root CAs.  There's no reason you should be using OpenSSL as described in that article to create certs for Google's websites.  Make sure your system time is correct, and you've applied all OS & browser updates.

Comment: Alright, well I honestly wouldn't know what would "look fishy". I'm uh... New to everything involving SSL until today apparently. Why would I clear it out? Wouldn't that make it impossible for me to view other sites that use HTTPS? ._.

Comment: That was embarrassing. I fixed it.

Comment: As Daniel Agans pointed out, the link was wrong. I fixed it, and am thoroughly embarrassed. -.-

Comment: Additionally, some more information could be useful:  What OS version & service pack are you running?  What browser version?  What specific websites are you trying to access?  Do you have this problem on other computers, or on the same computer with different browsers?  What's the exact error you are getting?  Can you bypass the error via some sort of "Proceed Anyway" option (usually available for cases such as this)?

Comment: Well like I said, there is absolutely no difference between the issue described in the article and mine, other than maybe details that he left out. 

I'm using Windows 7 Professional x64 SP1, and (Whatever the latest version of Chrome is). In Google Chrome, I don't have the option to proceed anyway. However, in other browsers including IE, It warns me but lets me pass.

Comment: Have you checked for any "hidden" updates in Windows Update?

Comment: The term "hidden" applying to Windows updates is new to me. 
I have no idea. I uh, feel really smart now...

Comment: Go to `Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Update`.  In the panel on the left, select "Restore hidden updates".  You will then see a list of updates which you or the system administrator have previously chosen to hide from the list of available updates - usually this will include things like Language Packs, or additional Microsoft software (e.g.: Silverlight) that you don't ever expect to need.  See if there's a Trusted Root CA or other security update among those.  If so, un-hide it and run the update.

Comment: Alright, well I looked for hidden updates and there's nothing.

Comment: @DanielAgans, that did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only issue I was having was with the cert that the various Google sites were issuing me...

- I clicked the lock at the left of the address bar and exported the certificate.
- Then I opened certmgr.msc and imported it to Trusted Root Certification Authorities.
- Restarted Chrome, and it worked.